# jQuery transit - rotation

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

Good day.

I'd like to rotate a div (which is already at an angle > 0, defined in css) around a center point.

The problem exhibits when I change the origin via `transformOrigin`, because initial rotation matrix is applied and then rotation starts from another point, in other words - div is repositioned. 
And it's not what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to preserve div's original rotation when transition is applied, and then apply rotation around a center point. If it were opengl I'd just do  translate/rotate/translate and so on, but I have no idea how to do it with css/jq.

So, I thought some of you guys are aware of a technique to achieve what I want? 
The one I have in mind comes from my gamedev experience and that's local coordinate space, I would then rotate my div in it's local space, and rotate that div in surrounding div's space. But I'm not that good with css/html and all that jazz, maybe some of you used the same technique? That would be great, yeah.

Oh, and here's a jsfiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3bnhT/1/

You can see that it immediately get's rotated by 60 degs (which is the problem), and then rotates by -60.

I hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
    http://jsfiddle.net/rachit_doshi/ZZ28s/

```
<img class="imageView" src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/164/6/2/ej_colored_doodle_by_sweetwatermelonsweet-d53b5tq.jpg" style="max-width:350px;max-height:350px;"></img>
<input type="hidden" id="angleInput" value="90" />
<input type="button" value="Rotate Right Side" id="right" />
<input type="button" value="Rotate Left Side" id="left" />
```